# Create Schema using Core Service

Tags: 2011, core-service

I am learning how to use the Tridion 2011 Core Service API and am trying to create a new folder containing a new `Person` schema with a single `Name` field.

When I run the following code I get the error `FaultException : Namespace URI must have a value`. If I uncomment the `personSchemaFields.Namespa...` it works fine but I'm pretty sure that this isn't the correct solution as I get errors later on when trying to use the schema (cannot find `uuid:[GUID]:Person`).

```
using (var client = new Tridion2011CoreService.CoreServiceClient())
{
    var newFolder = client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Folder, "tcm:4-160721-2");
    newFolder.Title = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
    newFolder = client.Create(newFolder, new ReadOptions());

    var personSchemaDataFields = new List<ItemFieldDefinitionData>();

    var personSchemaFieldName = new SingleLineTextFieldDefinitionData();
    personSchemaFieldName.Name = "Name";
    personSchemaFieldName.Description = "Name";
    personSchemaDataFields.Add(personSchemaFieldName);

    var personSchemaFields = new SchemaFieldsData();
    //personSchemaFields.NamespaceUri = "uuid:" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    personSchemaFields.RootElementName = "Person";
    personSchemaFields.Fields = personSchemaDataFields.ToArray();

    var personSchema = (SchemaData)client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Schema, newFolder.Id);
    personSchema.Title = "Person";
    personSchema.Description = "Person";
    personSchema.RootElementName = "Person";
    personSchema.Xsd = client.ConvertSchemaFieldsToXsd(personSchemaFields).ToString();
    // The next line generates the following error. "FaultException : Namespace URI must have a value."
    personSchema = (SchemaData)client.Create(personSchema, new ReadOptions());
}
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exception is correct. You should provide a `NamespaceUri` for the schema. The exception you get later on is telling you that you need to set `Content` property of your `ComponentData` that will match the schema. You can use `GetInstanceData` method to get default value of the `Content` XML

Comment: Should the personSchemaFields object have the same NamespaceUri as the personSchema?

Comment: Yes, as Content XML should also be in the same namespace

Comment: So after rearranging the code a little I set the `personSchemaFields.NamespaceUri` to the same value as `personSchema.NamespaceURi`. Thanks.